# Does a Synchronous Queue create a thread on each offer/put?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, queue, java.util.concurrent

I can not understand how the [Synchronous Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) works.
I understand that the idea is that the handover of tasks is to threads directly but the constructor does not have a bound e.g max number of threads like the other APIs.
So when a `put` or `offer` is done it is essentially passed to another thread or not?
So if I do e.g. 100 `put` it will be passed to 100 threads?
I tried to read the source code but could not figure out what happens. It seems to create a linked list of nodes where each node encapsulates a thread but how this list is maintained e.g. expand/shrink etc and how the treads run the tasks is not clear to me.
So does this list expand as we offer tasks? And as a result the consumer threads (waiters) increases constantly?
And are any of these reused? Or just execute something and stop?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you misunderstand the purpose of `SynchronousQueue`.

`SynchronousQueue` does not create any threads.
When you call `put`, `put` does not finish until another thread (a thread you created) has taken that element out of the `SynchronousQueue`.

"If I do e.g. 100 `put`" If you have a hundred threads, each calling `put` on the same `SynchronousQueue`, then all those threads will wait until other threads start to `take` those elements away.  If you have one thread, it will only do one `put` at a time, and each time it will wait for another thread to take that element before adding another.

The list used internally is a linked list, and it expands and gets GC'd like linked lists normally do.

Comment: If one of my threads then takes the data that another of my threads put then what is the need for the linked list?

Comment: The need is that you might have 100 threads, each with an element that's waiting to be taken.

Comment: So if I have `X` number of threads that need to take work of this queue how can I adjust the `X` number according to load? I.e. increase/decrease them accordingly?

Comment: In that case, a `SynchronousQueue` might not actually be the data structure you want -- perhaps instead of putting your objects into queues, you should be submitting them as tasks to an `Executors.newCachedThreadPool`.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that the idea is that the handover of tasks is to threads
>   directly but the constructor does not have a bound e.g max number of
>   threads like the other APIs.

Fist of all the int argument in the constructors of the queue implementations are of `SIZE` and not number of threads.

> So does this list expand as we offer tasks? And as a result the
>   consumer threads (waiters) increases constantly?

Synchronous Queue is used for purposes for hand-off. The `put()` call from the producer will block until there is a consumer that does `take()` from the queue. This has nothing to do with the count of threads. The consumer threads do not necessarily have to increase. Once the consumer has completed processing one message it can again do a take() from the queue.

```
public class MyWorker extends Thread {
    private final BlockingQueue<String> queue;
    public MyWorker(BlockingQueue<String> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while ( true ) {
                String s = queue.take();
                doWork(s);
            }
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException ie ) { 
            // just terminate
        }
    }
}

public class SyncQueueExample {
    // …    
    public SyncQueueExample() {
        try {
            int workItem = 0;
            // Create a synchronous queue
            BlockingQueue<String> queue = new SynchronousQueue<String>();

            // Create the child worker thread
            MyWorker worker = new MyWorker(queue);
            worker.start();

            // Start sending to the queue
            while ( true ) {
                System.out.println("\nPlacing work on queue");
                String work = "Work Item:" + (++workItem);
                queue.put(work);
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:** When run, the output between the queue producer and consumer will be "coordinated," in effect, and alternate as such:

```
Placing work on queue
Thread 'Thread-1' processing work: Work Item:1

Placing work on queue
Thread 'Thread-1' processing work: Work Item:2

Placing work on queue
Thread 'Thread-1' processing work: Work Item:3

Placing work on queue
Thread 'Thread-1' processing work: Work Item:4
```

More on [Synchronous Queue](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/java-concurrency-queue-processing-part-2/232900063)